# How to change the Keyboard layout on Solaris

Tags: solaris, keyboard-layout

I am running a machine with SunOS and NO graphical enviroment. Does someone know how to change the keyboard layout from the console??

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Select your layout

Type the following command to select your layout from a list:

```
kbd -s
```

If your language isn't in the list, have a look at this [blog post on how to create your own layout](http://iks.cs.ovgu.de/~elkner/keyboard/kbdhowto.html). You might have to take a look at this if you have a non-standard (e.g. Apple) layout.

## Reload your keymap

Reload your keyboard translation table with the following command:

```
loadkeys
```

The change should persist through reboots, unless you're using an in-memory OS like SmartOS

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the loadkeys command

Answer (score 1):

If it's running a recent Solaris 10 update release or patch set, or a release newer than Solaris 10 (such as Solaris Express or OpenSolaris), try *kbd -s* -- on older Solaris x86 releases, try *kdmconfig*.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `LAYOUT` value in `/etc/default/kbd` (use `kbd -s` to get a list of allowed values). Then run `kbd -i` and finally reboot.

Answer (score 0):

From [Keyboard Layout on the Console](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37838_01/html/E61001/glmlj.html)

> To view the current console keyboard layout setting:
>
> ```
> $ nlsadm get-console-keymap 
> keymap=US-English
> ```
>
> To list available values for the console keyboard layout setting:
>
> ```
> $ nlsadm list-console-keymap
> Arabic
>  ...
> ```
>
> To set the console keyboard layout to Japanese:
>
> ```
> # nlsadm set-console-keymap Japanese
> ```

See also:

- [`man nlsadm`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36871/nlsadm-1m.html)